# Is There anyway to execute multiple commands in vscode keybindings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to execute multiple commands in keybindings.json in vscode to be able to log variable name, filename and the variable value.

ex in dart

```
double x = 2.2;
print("main.dart -> x $x");
```

the default behavior is to insertSnippet in the same line but i need to go to add new line below my variable then insert my custom snippet.

In addition i tried macros and multi-command. Unforgettably i couldn't reach the VSCode environment variables like TM_FILENAME_BASE and CLIPBOARD. They just print as a plane text something like

```
double x = 2.2;
print("$TM_FILENAME_BASE x $x")
```

Not able to resolve the env var to it's value.

this is from **mutli-command** extension *settings.json*

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "myCommand",
            "sequence": [
                "cursorDown",
                "insertSnippet",
                {
                    "command": "type",
                    "args": {
                        "text": "print(\" log-> ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} -> 
                       ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} -> ${${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}} \" );"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
```

and this one from *keybindings.json*

```
{
     "key": "alt+p",
     "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
     "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceExtname == .dart",
     "args": {
         "snippet": "print(\" log-> ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} -> ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} -> ${${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}} \" );"
     }
}
```

**SOLUTION**
This is a tweaked solution for my issue inspired by Mark

from *settings.json*

```
 "multiCommand.commands": [
        {
            "command": "multiCommand.printVariable",
            "sequence": [
                "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction", // Copy the selected to the clipboard 
                "editor.action.insertLineAfter", 
                {
                    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
                    "args": {
                        "snippet": "print(\"${TM_FILENAME_BASE} -> ${CLIPBOARD} -> ${${CLIPBOARD}}\");" // then add it here 
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
```

from *keybindings.json*

```
 {
        "key": "alt+p",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "command": "multiCommand.printVariable"
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceExtname == .dart"
 }
```

Comment: Please show your snippet and/or macro.  So we can help fix what you wrote rather than writing it ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select your variable, this gives your desired output:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.printVariable",

    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "print(\"${TM_FILENAME_BASE} -> "
        }
      },
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": " $"
        }
      },
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "\");"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

You used the `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` so I did as well - it will strip off the extension - but you showed `main.dart` as part of your desired output so perhaps you wanted `TM_FILENAME`?

and your keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+p",    // or whichever keybinding you choose
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.printVariable" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceExtname == .dart" 
},
```

---

Similarly to my answer [How to create a shortcut to print a variable (vscode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182207/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-print-a-variable-vscode/56189228#56189228)

if your input is of the general form

```
double x = 2.2;  // where the desired variable is right before an `=`
```

you can simplify this alot and only use the following keybinding (and no macro) with your **cursor at the end of the line** - no selection:

```
{
  "key": "alt+p",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
              // works with cursor end of line, no selection
    "snippet": "\nprint(\"${TM_FILENAME_BASE} -> ${TM_CURRENT_LINE/\\s*\\w*\\b\\s*(.*?)\\s*=.*/$1 $$1\");/}",
  },
   "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceExtname == .dart" 
},
```

---

Demo of both approaches.  First with the selection and macro.  Second, no selection, cursor at end of line and simple snippet.

Note I am in my `keybindings.json` file and so `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` = `keybindings`.

[image: print variables demo]

Comment: Great, this is very helpful thanks a lot. I just tweaked the multiCommand a little bit i will add it in the description.

Comment: Of course, I temporarily forgot about the ${CLIPBOARD} variable which I am well aware of - slip of the mind, good catch.